# DDD init file corrupted by gdb

Tags: linux, cross-compiling, ddd-debugger

There is a well known DDD bug that does not allow it to boot when the init file becomes corrupt.

This file is automatically created at directory .ddd, in the root user, with every boot.
It must be erased each time it gets corrupted in order to run DDD.

Doing some tests, I noticed that this file is corrupted when you enter into the gdb "settings edit" menu. Reading a corrupted file "init" with text editor, I found several lines that begin with the word "set". Replacing occurrences of `"set "` with `"! "` (without quotes) makes the file operational without needing to erase it.

I am running Debian "wheezy" Linux on a Core i3 processor (64-bit). What is responsible for this strange behavior?

Comment: I use DDD quite often, never heard of this issue, nor experienced it.  Please define "well known"... can you give examples or URL's?  'set' is a command to set an options value, while the '!' is a comment marker.  Your terminology is odd too... "boot?? (perhaps, every execution?)  "root?" (are you running as root? or are you referring to your current user?)  Never had any issues with DDD's gdb settings menu.

Comment: The configuration file is corrupted when I enter>menu>edit>gdb settings. When .ddd/init becomes corrupt the program hangs "opening session..". If I force the output it send "Gdb still busy. Exit anyway (and kill it)?". Then, with a script I made I need to delete the .ddd/init file to get ddd again operative. I put below how .ddd/init is when becomes corrupted.

! DO NOT ADD ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE -- DDD WILL OVERWRITE IT
Ddd*dddinitVersion: 3.3.12

! Debugger settings.
Ddd*autoDebugger: on
Ddd*debugger: gdb
set auto-solib-add on\n\
set backtrace past-entry off\n\
...
a lot of Set!